# How to write PCF command to get channel status with a condition?

Tags: java, ibm-mq, pcf

Is there a way to write a PCF program to get channel status for Cluster Sender/Receiver channels which are in "Running" status?
I have something like this which gives me channel status of only one channel!

```
 // send the request and collect the responses 
    String checkStatus="";
    String channelName ="";
 // build a request 
    request = new PCFMessage(CMQCFC.MQCMD_INQUIRE_CHANNEL_STATUS); 
 // add a parameter designating the name of the channel for which status is requested 
    request.addParameter(CMQCFC.MQCACH_CHANNEL_NAME, "TO.*"); 
 // add a parameter designating the instance type (current) desired 
    request.addParameter(CMQCFC.MQIACH_CHANNEL_INSTANCE_TYPE, CMQC.MQOT_CURRENT_CHANNEL); 

    responses = agent.send(request); 
    for (int j = 0; j < responses.length; j++) { 
         //  get the channel name and trim the spaces 
        String temp ="";
        temp = responses[j].getStringParameterValue(CMQCFC.MQCACH_CHANNEL_NAME); 
        channelName = temp.trim(); 

        int chlStatus = responses[j].getIntParameterValue(CMQCFC.MQIACH_CHANNEL_STATUS); 
        //System.out.println("channel status: " + chlStatus); 
        String[] chStatusText = { 
            "", "MQCHS_BINDING", "MQCHS_STARTING", "MQCHS_RUNNING", 
                "MQCHS_STOPPING", "MQCHS_RETRYING", "MQCHS_STOPPED", 
                "MQCHS_REQUESTING", "MQCHS_PAUSED", 
                "", "", "", "", "MQCHS_INITIALIZING" 
        }; 
        checkStatus = chStatusText[chlStatus]; 
        //System.out.println("channel status: " + checkStatus); 
    } 
    System.out.println("chl: " + channelName + " STATUS: " + checkStatus  + ")");
```

The above code gives channel status for only one channel and not all the channels. What is wrong here?

Comment: Are you asking how to translate the integer you have got back into Running (or other states) or are you asking how to get other information from the channel status record as well as the Running state?

Comment: Basically I would like to write a PCF command corresponding to the below runmqsc                                                                                                                                        dis chs(TO.*) where( STATUS eq RUNNING)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The PCF part of your code looks fine, but the printing out of the result is the code in error.

```
responses = agent.send(request); 
for (int j = 0; j < responses.length; j++) { 
    :
    :
    checkStatus = chStatusText[chlStatus];
} 
System.out.println("chl: " + channelName + " STATUS: " + checkStatus  + ")");
```

You have a for loop going round all the responses, but then the `println` is outside the for loop and thus is only printing out the result for the final response.

Comment: Thanks! I need more sleep I guess :)

Comment: I have 2 channels. It works for server-connection channel through which I connect to queue manager.  For other channel it fails as,  AMQ9502: Type of channel not suitable for action requested.

EXPLANATION:
The operation requested cannot be performed on channel 'remote.local'. Some
operations are only valid for certain channel types. This channel is a
'RECEIVER' channel type. For example, you can only ping or trigger a channel
from the initiating end.

Comment: You have appended your comment on a question about DISPLAYing a channel. Are you saying that when you try to display a channel you get this error? All you says is "It works ..." you don't say what "it" is. Suggest you might want to start a new question rather than tag onto the end of this one if you're doing something different?

Answer (score 1):

Go grab my open source project called [MQ Channel Monitor](http://www.capitalware.com/mqcm_overview.html).  Download the source code and review the 'PCFChlStatus.java' file.  There is a method called getMCAStatus() which is basically what you are after.